# How to catch synchronization end of folders(send/receive) in Outlook VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Simple question, I need to load data(stored as storage items in the inbox folder) after Outlook finishes synchronization of this folder. My current code:

```
private Outlook.Explorer _currentExplorer;
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();
    _currentExplorer.Session.SyncObjects[1].SyncEnd += SyncEnd_Event;
    // also tried:  
    //_currentExplorer.Session.SyncObjects.AppFolders.SyncEnd += SyncEnd_Event;
}

private void SyncEnd_Event()
{
    MyAddin.LoadData();
}
```

I used `SyncObjects[1]` because I found that it should be "Send/Receive All" But my `SyncEnd_Event()` is never fired.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SyncEnd  event will not fire in your case because the object raising the events (SyncObject) is an implicit variable created by the compiler. Ass soon as GC releases it, no events will fire.
Store SyncObject object in a dedicated global (class) variable and set event handlers on it.

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks! Also, I had to add `SyncObject.Start()` otherwise it didn't work.

Comment: It would work without Start, but only when Outlook starts Send/Receive automatically or when the user hits Ctrl+M.